# Деплой war на томкат - как понять в чем ошибка?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deploy

Пытаюсь задепроить spring boot  приложение,
С веб интерфейса при попытке стартовать его получаю:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /registry could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/registry]]
```

Логи томката помогаюют не сильно - какое то исключение

```
SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /registry could not be started
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/registry]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    
...

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [WebappLoader[/registry]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5881)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @66bcfe07 attempted duplicate class definition for org.apache.catalina.loader.JdbcLeakPrevention. (org.apache.catalina.loader.JdbcLeakPrevention is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @66bcfe07, parent loader java.net.URLClassLoader @27716f4)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2300)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2223)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2123)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    ... 34 more
```

Что дальше можно сделать чтобы понять в чем ошибка? Как отлаживать?
запуск просто mvn spring-boot:run  работает прекрасно.